# Find the exact float values in the columns ending with .000 and sum up their occurrences in the newest column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data frame with the columns:
[Data frame columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4BuV.png)

```
'time', 'bp1', 'bs1', 'bp2', 'bs2', 'bp3', 'bs3', 'bp4', 'bs4', 'bp5',
       'bs5', 'bp6', 'bs6', 'bp7', 'bs7', 'bp8', 'bs8', 'bp9', 'bs9', 'bp10',
       'bs10', 'ap1', 'as1', 'ap2', 'as2', 'ap3', 'as3', 'ap4', 'as4', 'ap5',
       'as5', 'ap6', 'as6', 'ap7', 'as7', 'ap8', 'as8', 'ap9', 'as9', 'ap10',
       'as10'
```

I need to use only columns with "s" like "bs1","bs2"..."as10"
The task is to return the values of these columns row-wise which end with 0s:
for instance 5.0, 10.0 -floats with 0 after the comma, and count their occurrences in the new column "absolut_frequency" as 1+ 1+ 1 + 1 if for instance in 1 row per 1 timestamp I have bs1=4.0 and as2=5.0 only the absolute frequency would return 2 in total.
Here is what I am trying to see but I need to catch them in all columns with "s" simultaneously with the correct condition and sum. up per row.
[Search for values with .0 after comma in the columns with 's'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fItNT.png)

what I produced is not working

```
btc['abs_frq'] = 0

for key, value in btc.iteritems():
    
if key in btc.loc[:, 2:41:2] and value[np.isclose.values, .000]:
        btc['abs_frq'] += 1

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [2] of type int

or also:

btc['absolute frequency'] = 0

for column, data in btc.columns[2:41:2]:
    #columnSeriesObj = btc[column]
        
    #if columnSeriesObj.values[np.isclose((btc.column % 3).values, .000)]:
    if data[np.isclose.values, .000] in column:
        btc['absolute frequency'] += 1
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can one please help me how to iterate through rows and columns correctly, searching for exact float values with .0,.00, .000 endings and summing up their occurrences in a row in the new column?

Thank you,
Marina

Comment: you must provide a **minimal** reproducible example, images are not OK

Comment: Please post some data and a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.